# “A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method

Tags: c#

My project has a class ‘mybutton’.

```
namespace Project.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    public class myButton 
    {
        public myButton()
        {
            Clickable = false;
            Selected = false;
            Url = "";
        }

        public myButton(string displayText, string url) : this()
        {
            DisplayText = displayText;
            Url = url;
        }

        public bool Clickable { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

    }
}
```

When I try to create a new instance of myButton from another class I get the error “A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method...” (red squiggle over url).

```
public class PageElements
{
    url =”url goes here”;
    public myButton CancelButton = new myButton("Cancel Order", url);
    …
    …
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561548/c-sharp-forms-objectarray-outside-method#comment32565477_21561548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says to move the initialization of CancelButton into PageElements constructor. Ii order to work what you tried to do  the *url*  should have been either **static** or **constant**

Answer (score 0):

use

```
const string url =”url goes here”;
```

or

```
static string url =”url goes here”;
```