# How to resolve "'UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' ..." error?

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

i am writing a game in unity and i want to create
one random integer number... i am using the following:

```
public Random ran = new Random();
public int power = ran.Next(0, 10);
```

but when i want to run the program it gives me the following error:

> Type 'UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and no
>   extension method 'Next' of type `UnityEngine.Random' could be found 
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone help me on what is going wrong ???

Comment: Are you trying to use System.Random (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  Looks like your code is using something from Unity instead.  Try adding a `System.` before both instances of `Random`.

Comment: And your next question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564610/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method

Comment: @HenkHolterman, good catch; I didn't even notice that these were fields.

Comment: thank you a lot all of you :) I will try what you suggested to me and i will let you know what is happening !!! and hopefully to help and others that have similar problems !! but again thanks :)

Answer (score 26):

You should use the `System.Random` class, since this class has a method called `Next`. For further documentation on this please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random(v=vs.110).aspx). I suppose that this is your error, since from the error message you get, it's clear that the `UnityEngine.Random` class is used and not the `System.Random`. In terms of code, I would try this:

```
public System.Random ran = new System.Random();
public int power = ran.Next(0, 10);
```

**Update**

Using the `System.Random` we will solve the issue of the naming collision but another problem would be arise. Typing the above two lines inside the body of a class, like below:

```
public class Program
{
    public System.Random ran = new System.Random();
    public int power = ran.Next(0, 10);
}
```

you will notice that the compiler warns you that something wrong is going on and if you try to build your project, you will get the following message:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

In order to fix this, there are two options:

a) Make `ran` to be static:

```
public class Program
{
    public static System.Random ran = new System.Random();
    public int power = ran.Next(0, 10);
}
```

b) Move the initialization of `power` inside the constructor:

```
public class Program
{
    public System.Random ran = new System.Random();
    public int power;

    public Program()
    {
       power = ran.Next(0, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: @HenkHolterman I got you. I will update my post correspondingly. Thanks for the good catch.

Comment: nXu what you sent me (public System.Random ran = new System.Random();) is just perfect :) it fully works without any errors and without the need to include any library or class in the program !!!

Comment: Don't use System.Random in Unity! It will not generate varying numbers under certain conditions, related to Unity's gameloop.

Comment: Thanks it helped :)  - needed using System.Linq & public static System.Random ran = new System.Random();

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var number = Random.Range(0,10);
```

Comment: This answer is poor because it doesn't explain why this should work, but if I am not in error the UnityEngine class Random has the Range static method. For example: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/467766/randomrange-help.html Whoever downvoted this should reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a built in Random class. Instead you can use:

```
    var randomNumber = Random.Range(10);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be significantly different from the answer given by DoanCan. Perhaps you could add some explanation of why you think this is better.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Unity has its own pseudo-random number generator, which is what you are automatically picking up, and as nightRider has said the syntax for that PRNG would be `var number = Random.Range(0,10)`;

It's usually floats that you want in Unity, so using Unity's own PRNG avoids the *possible* overhead (I've not tested it) of having to generate doubles and casting them to floats, and it also automatically gives a single PRNG for all scripts, which can simplify debugging when you want to initialise the PRNG with a seed for consistent behaviour. It also offers some other game-oriented methods and properties such as generating random points inside or on a unit sphere. On the other hand, it does not provide bit or double pseudo-random numbers, so if you want a lot of those then System.Random might be a better choice, though for repeatable behaviour when debugging you'll want to make that PRNG common to all scripts and seed it just once, which is a bit of an extra headache.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the "Using System"? Because if you write Random it does not know if you mean the Random in System or UnityEngine.